# How do I preserve markup tags?

Tags: xml, xslt

I've got an XML document containing news stories, and the body element of a news story contains p tags amongst the plain text. When I use XSL to retrieve the body, e.g.

```
<xsl:value-of select="body" />
```

the p tags seem to get stripped out. I'm using Visual Studio 2005's implementation of XSL.

Does anyone have any ideas how to avoid this? Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try to use

```
<xsl:copy-of select="body"/>
```

instead. From [w3schools' documentation on same](http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/el_copy-of.asp):

> The `<xsl:copy-of>` element creates a
>   copy of the current node.
>
> Note: Namespace nodes, child nodes,
>   and attributes of the current node are
>   automatically copied as well!

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have control over the input document, copy-of should work:

From http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/06/07/transforming/index.html

"The xsl:copy-of element, on the other hand, can copy the entire subtree of each node that the template selects. This includes attributes, if the xsl:copy-of element's select attribute has the appropriate value. In the following example, the template copies title element nodes and all of their descendant nodes -- in other words, the complete title elements, including their tags, subelements, and attributes:"

```
<xsl:template match="title">
  <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work, I followed Blair Conrad's suggestion as I saw that first but you've both said the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the input document, [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) is the right way to go.

Comment: If I wrap my nested HTML using CDATA, I get the literal HTML, I want to retain line-feeds (i.e. paragraph tags).

Answer (score 1):

The value of an XML element - this is true not just in XSLT but in DOM implementations - is the concatenation of all of its descendant text nodes.  In XSLT, `value-of` emits an element's value, while `copy-of` emits a copy of the element.

Answer (score -1):

It is because the engine is interpreting the <p> tag (excluding it for the output). You need to specify you want the content "as it is", using the "disable-output-escaping=yes|no" attribute.

```
<xsl:value-of select="body" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Comment: disable-output-escaping is for enabling/disabling the escaping of reserved characters (> becomes > or stays >).