# XSLT finding links inside tags in XML documents

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there a way to have an xsl stylesheet recognize when a link appears inside a tag in an xml document and turn it into a working link?

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="guys.xsl"?>

<people>
   <person>
      <name>Guy 1</name>
      <bio>Guy 1 is a guy.</bio>
   </person>

   <person>
      <name>Guy 2</name>
      <bio>Guy 2 is from <a href="http://www.example.com">somewhere</a>.</bio>
   </person>
</people>
```

Guy 1's bio should just appear as regular text, Guy 2's bio should have a working link in it.

Comment: Yes, it is.  If you post your "guys.xsl" we can tell you why the links aren't being rendered.

Comment: Also, tell us the ultimate destination of the XSL output -- is it going to a browser or some other rendering mechanism?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a complete solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to have an xsl
>   stylesheet recognize when a link
>   appears inside a tag in an xml
>   document and turn it into a working
>   link?

**Yes. This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <table border="1">
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </table>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="person">
   <tr>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </tr>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="person/*">
   <td><xsl:copy-of select="node()"/></td>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<people>
   <person>
      <name>Guy 1</name>
      <bio>Guy 1 is a guy.</bio>
   </person>

   <person>
      <name>Guy 2</name>
      <bio>Guy 2 is from <a href="http://www.example.com">somewhere</a>.</bio>
   </person>
</people>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>Guy 1</td>
      <td>Guy 1 is a guy.</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td>Guy 2</td>
      <td>Guy 2 is from <a href="http://www.example.com">somewhere</a>.</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect. This does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This will work right out of the box if you are trying to display this in html format:

```
<html>
<body>
  <xsl:for-each select="people/person">
     <div>
       <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
     </div>
     <div>
       <xsl:copy-of select="bio"/>
     </div>
  </xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: changed value-of to copy-of. See this discussion:
[How do I preserve markup tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162225/how-do-i-preserve-markup-tags-when-using-xslt)