# XSL stripping paragraphs/line-feeds (C#)

Tags: c#, html, xslt, whitespace, paragraph

I have the following code which is removing paragraph tags/whitespace in the HTML. Is there a way to fix?

Cut-down XSL:

```
<div style="FONT-WEIGHT: normal" align="left">
 <span class="xdExpressionBox xdDataBindingUI" title="" tabIndex="-1" xd:xctname="ExpressionBox" xd:CtrlId="CTRL35" xd:disableEditing="yes" style="WIDTH: 100%; FONT-SIZE: 11.5pt">
    <xsl:value-of select="my:IncidentSummaryDetails/my:incidentDetails/my:incidentDetailsHeader"/>
 </span>
```

Cut-down XML:

```
<my:incidentDetailsHeader>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:space="preserve">
  <p style="text-align:justify;">​Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet laboris fugiat shankle aute consectetur leberkas. Tempor irure aliqua, pastrami venison sint turkey.</p>
  <p style="text-align:justify;"><span lang="EN-US" style="text-decoration:underline;"><strong>SPACE</strong><strong></strong></span></p>
  <p style="text-align:justify;">Cow dolore turkey voluptate cupidatat </p>
 </html>
</my:incidentDetailsHeader>
```

HTML result (I've circled the expected spaces - the above cut-down XML only shows one instance of "SPACE" I know):

[image]

I am using the `XslCompiledTransform` class to perfrom the XSL transformation and the result removes the `<p>` tags from above. I would like to either retain the p tag, or insert two `<br />` tags for example.

As you can see the setting is `xml:space="preserve"` and there's no `strip-space` or `normalize-space` set anywhere in the XSL.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `<xsl:copy-of>` as per this article here: [How do I preserve markup tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162225/how-do-i-preserve-markup-tags-when-using-xslt)

As an aside: this was for InfoPath, and so instead of using a Calculated Value, I simply had to use a read-only Rich Text Box which did a copy-of itself.